# How do you count subdirectories in a folder?

Tags: python, subdirectory

I figured out how to count directories in a folder, but not sure how I could edit my code to recursively count subdirectories. Any help would be appreciated.

This is my code so far.

```
def nestingLevel(path):
    count = 0
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        if item[0] != '.':
            n = os.path.join(path,item)
            if os.path.isdir(n):
                count += 1 + nestingLevel(n)
    return count
```

Comment: `count = len([d for d in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(d)])`. If you need to go deeper, look into `os.walk`

Comment: [Walk the tree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk), you must: `os.walk()`.

Comment: Also, unlike some other languages, `os.listdir()` does not return `.` or `..`, so you don't need to check for that.

Comment: Use [`os.path.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.split) and use the length of the sequence it returns to determine the count.

Answer (score 5):

I think you may want to use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
import os

def fcount(path):
    count1 = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            count1 += len(dirs)

    return count1

path = "/home/"
print fcount(path)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a glob here - the `**` pattern indicates a recursive glob.  The trailing slash matches on directories, excluding other types of files.

```
from pathlib import Path

def recursive_subdir_count(path):
    dirs = Path(path).glob('**/')
    result = sum(1 for dir in dirs)
    result -= 1  # discount `path` itself
```

Using `/` works on windows, macOS, and Linux, so don't worry about putting `os.sep` instead.

***Beware of a weird edge case:*** shell globs typically exclude hidden directories, i.e. those which begin with a `.`, but `pathlib` includes those (it's a feature, not a bug: see [issue26096](https://bugs.python.org/issue26096)). If you care about discounting hidden directories, filter them out in the expression when calling `sum`. Or, use the older module [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) which excludes them by default.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I think I'd lead with pathlib, especially since you say it's more performant, '.' instead of `path`, and use `rglob('')` instead of `glob('**/')`. and you might give an example and print the directories to illustrate that `.` is an included directory.

Comment: @AaronHall  I've just edited to remove the `glob` example, since it doesn't really offer any advantage over `pathlib`. And I'll have to disagree that `rglob` is preferable here - yielding dirs when using the empty pattern is not obvious at all to me. In contrast, putting a trailing slash for matching dirs is familiar from shells.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count them all without the root, this will do it:

```
len([i for i, j, k in os.walk('.')])-1
```